# Adjust div width according to button rows width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some buttons inside a div which, being many, form new rows down, so I've made a vertical scroll inside that div to have access to all those buttons.

The problem is that the vertical scroll is not next to the buttons, and that is what I need, but it is difficult because the width of a row of buttons will always vary according to the width of the screen.

In the snipet, if you change of your screen width, you can see that great variable space between the buttons and the scroll, I have put colors to the main divs for better distinction:

```css
body{
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

#sentlist{
 height: 55px;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

#sli{
 width:auto;
 background-color: #EEAAEE;
}

.otradiv{
 height:50px;
 background-color:orange;
}

button{
  width:50px;
  height:23px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Hi</title>

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inner navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="sentlist" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-11">
        <div id="sli">
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <div class="row otradiv">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, whatever the width of the screen, is there any way to eliminate the space between the buttons and the scroll?

**edit**:
Cause snipets here can't be resized, [here's](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxMgLz#anon-login) a codepen:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use flex**

```
 #sli .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -moz-justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -moz-justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-container .item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 23px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0px 1.1% 8px;
}
.flex-dummy {
    height: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.flex-container .item>button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.otradiv {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
}
#sentlist {
    height: 55px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#sli {
    width: auto;
    background-color: #EEAAEE;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inner navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="sentlist" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-11">
        <div id="sli">
   <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
      <div class="item"><button></button></div>
    
    <!-- add fill dummys here. The number of dummys must be the number of possible columns minus one -->
    <div class="item flex-dummy"></div>
    <div class="item flex-dummy"></div>
    <div class="item flex-dummy"></div>
    <div class="item flex-dummy"></div>
    <div class="item flex-dummy"></div>
    <div class="item flex-dummy"></div>
    <div class="item flex-dummy"></div>
    <div class="item flex-dummy"></div>
    <div class="item flex-dummy"></div>
    <div class="item flex-dummy"></div>
    
   </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <div class="row otradiv">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice solution, but it still has an issue on the last row. If you increase your screen width, the centered last buttons doesn't look properly. Any fix for it?

Comment: would you like to use "justify-content: flex-end;"

Comment: that makes a space at the beggining of the buttons

Comment: that's what I was looking for, ty so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is unwanted padding on div#sentlist which is creating the space between div#sli and the scroll bar. You need to remove the padding from div#sentlist.

```
  #sentlist{
    height: 55px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0; //remove bootstrap padding
  }
```

Also, it is typically best practice to use classes rather than the id in your css file.